# Is it possible to return value from ruby script and read that value inside c or shell script?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, ubuntu

How can we return value from ruby script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

a = "test"
a
```

How can we access the value of 'a' in Ubuntu terminal or java or c?

Comment: Print it. Ruby vars are just that: Ruby vars. You can also exit with a value.

Comment: @DaveNewton is correct you can use  STDOUT which print and puts both utilize as `$stdout`. This will output to the standard output stream. You could also right the results to a file and parse the file after the script completes. Here is a nice little post on the subject of [IO in Ruby](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/io/)

Comment: Supposing you don't have access to the script. You want to run any arbitrary ruby script, and output what it evaluates to AS THOUGH calling p or pp on the final value, but without being able to edit the script itself.

Answer (score 11):

print your variable within ruby/python script, it can then be read from a shell script by example :

```
#!/bin/bash
ruby_var=$(ruby myrubyscript.rb)
python_var=$(python mypythonscript.py)

echo "$ruby_var"
echo "$python_var"
```

take care your ruby/python script only print this variable ( there are more complicated ways with named pipes by example for more interaction ).

Comment: thanks for +1  but my answer is out of subject given it is ruby. anyway , print in ruby or in python is the very same way.

Answer (score 4):

If the value is an integer between 0 and 255, you can use the exit status

```
$ ruby -e 'var=42; exit var'
$ val=$?
$ echo $val
42
```

Comment: Is it possible to return the filename? Is there any other way to access the filename ?

Comment: Note that an exit status of anything other than zero indicates an error.

Comment: @krunalshah, you want philippe lhardy's answer to return a string from the child process to the shell.

Comment: @Ajedi32, by convention yes. But since there are 256 possible exit status, it can convey more information than the binary "success|failure" status.

Comment: @glennjackman Well, it's a little more than _just_ convention. There are many commonly used Unix commands and processes into which this convention is heavily ingrained. For example, try running `set -e` in your terminal, then try that example in your answer again. My point is, while you technically _can_ use the exit status to return values from Unix commands, I wouldn't recommend using it in a real application for anything other than error codes.